# Unit testing in React + Mocha + Enzyme i + Webpack - how to ignore imported files?

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, mocha.js, webpack, enzyme

I'm trying to Unit Test React on the Front End in Mocha & Enzyme. The testing stops when Mocha gets into the app file and parses over import statements:

```
import 'script!jquery';
import 'script!what-input';
import 'script!foundation-sites';
```

I was able to ignore .css and .scss files in the package.json test command:

```
"test": "mocha --compilers js:babel-register --require ./test/client/test_helper.js --require ignore-styles --recursive",
"test/client:watch": "npm test -- --watch"
```

I'm not clear on how to ignore these import files, and if I'm going about this the wrong way. (I found the solution for ignore-styles here in Stack Overflow but not something like this.

The error I get:

```
module.js:341
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'script!jquery'
```

New to Unit testing, any help appreciated.

update:
// babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "stage-0", "react"],
  "plugins": ["transform-runtime"],
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "presets": ["react-hmre"]
    },
    "production": {
      "presets": ["react-hmre"]
    }
  }
}

// webpack.config.js 
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var HtmlWebpackPluginConfig = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: __dirname + '/client/index.html',
  filename: 'index.html',
  inject: 'body'
});

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  entry: [
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
    './client/index.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new ExtractTextPlugin("bundle.css"),
    HtmlWebpackPluginConfig
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loaders: [ 'babel' ],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        include: path.join(__dirname, 'client')
      },
      // fonts and svg
      { test: /\.woff(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff" },
      { test: /\.woff2(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff" },
      { test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream" },
      { test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "file" },
      { test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml" },
      {
        // images
        test: /\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif)$/,
        loader: "file"
      },
      {
        // for some modules like foundation
        test: /\.scss$/,
        exclude: [/node_modules/], // sassLoader will include node_modules explicitly
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style", "css!postcss!sass?outputStyle=expanded")
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style", "css!postcss")
      }
    ]
  },
  postcss: function(webpack) {
    return [
      autoprefixer({browsers: ['last 2 versions', 'ie >= 9', 'and_chr >= 2.3']})
    ];
  },
  sassLoader: {
    includePaths: [path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules")]
  }
};
```

script/run.sh points to a test-helper file:

```
/* jshint undef: false, unused: false */

process.env.NODE_ENV = 'test';

// The following allows you to require files independent of
// the location of your test file.
// Example:
//  var User = require(__server + '/models/user.js')
//
global.__server = __dirname + '/../server';
global.__client = __dirname + '/../client';

//
// Assertions
//
var chai = require('chai');
// Option 1: Make the `expect` function available in every test file
global.expect = chai.expect;
// Option 2: Make everything should-able
// global.should = chai.should()


//
// Helper Functions
//
// This is the object you can attach any helper functions used across
// several test files.
global.TestHelper = {};

var db       = require('../server/db.js');

TestHelper.setup = function(){
  return db.deleteEverything();
};

//
// Mock apps for API testing
//
var express = require('express');

TestHelper.createApp = function (loader) {
  var app = express();
  app.use(require('body-parser').json());

  app.testReady = function () {
    // Log all errors
    app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
      console.error('==Error==');
      console.error('   ' + err.stack);
      next(err);
    });
  };
  return app;
};

//
// Mocha "helpers" to support coroutines tests
//
var Bluebird = require('bluebird');

global.before_ = function (f) { before ( Bluebird.coroutine(f) ); };
global.beforeEach_ = function (f) { beforeEach ( Bluebird.coroutine(f) ); };
global.it_ = function (description, f) { it ( description, Bluebird.coroutine(f) ); };
global.xit_ = function (description, f) { xit ( description, f ); };
global.it_.only = function (description, f) { it.only( description, Bluebird.coroutine(f) ); };
```

I'm not entirely sure how the helper file is well, helping, since the back end team member put it together for his unit tests - but it looks like it could be promising.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: add all important files to help us to find the problem : .babelrc, webpack.config.js, etc.. please

Comment: Hi Louis, I added the files, do you have a suggestion on how to ignore those import files?